# First and last members of a group

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay

***Solve these two riddles***

---

1. *It is the first member in a group of seven. If it joins hands with its twin, they're no longer there. With the help of a Chinese billionaire, the twins become a capital city.*

---

2. *It is the last member in a group of seven. If it joins hands with its twin, they're found in South America. With the help of an indefinite article, the twins become a painter.*

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group of seven here is:

> the seven notes of **[Solfège](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge)** in music: do, re mi, fa, so(l), la, and ti.

**Riddle 1:**

> The first member of this group of seven is **DO**. Two of them concatenated together (when '*it joins hands with its twin*') make **DODO**, an extinct bird (*no longer there*). When we furthermore add '[MA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Ma)' (a famous *Chinese billionaire*), we get **[DODOMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodoma)**, the *capital city* of Tanzania.

**Riddle 2:**

> The last member of this group of seven is **TI**. Concatenated with itself (as per DO, above) yields **[TITI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titi)**, a monkey native to *South America*. When we furthermore add 'AN' ('*an indefinite article*'), we get **[TITIAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titian)**, a famous *painter* of the Renaissance era.

Comment: How did I know it was you when the "one new answer" bar showed up? `:)`